# Proper pattern for merging curved lines into one geometry?

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

I've got thousands of sparsely arranged curved lines (made with CubicBezierCurve3) being merged into one geometry for obvious performance reasons.

Is it possible to feed them all into a single THREE.Line without the interconnecting segments becoming connected?  Or make those interconnecting line segments invisible?

LinePieces/LineSegments (line strip) would work, but it would double the number of vertices and doesn't seem like the right approach..

Comment: looks like adding a NaN vertex is accepted by OpenGL for breaks along a GL_LINE.  However, three.js fails on a bounding sphere computation because it can't handle NaN vertices!

Comment: Why not to use indices and an indexed buffer geometry?

Comment: @prisoner849 not sure how an index would work in this specific application - can you elaborate?

Comment: Buffer geometry + indices + custom attribute for visibility.

Comment: @prisoner849 the answer I gave below seems to be the most straightforward.  WebGL does recognize NaN vertices as breaks in a GL_LINE, but three.js couldn't handle it without a specific workaround.  There's no need to have another data structure (and corresponding memory usage) for this visibility information.

Comment: The devil hides in details. What will happen when you try to call `.computeLineDistances()` method of `THREE.Line()`? If you want dashed lines for some reasons.

Comment: @prisoner849 a failure of `computeLineDistances()` on GL-compliant code should be considered a bug in three.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So yes you can in fact send over NaN to instruct OpenGL to jump.  Then just give three.js a bogus empty bounding sphere (or do a proper calculation of if).  The bogus bounding sphere will mess up normal calculation, which didn't matter in my use but might in others'.  Here's the pseudocode solution:

```
var positions = [];

for(....)
{
    ...
    var pts = curve.getPoints(...);
    for(var p = 0; p < pts.length; p++)
        positions.push(pts[p].x, pts[p].y, pts[p].z);

    positions.push(NaN, NaN, NaN);
}

var geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
geometry.addAttribute( 'position', new THREE.BufferAttribute( new Float32Array(positions), 3, true ) );
geometry.boundingSphere = new THREE.Sphere();
```

Comment: I understand their position, but they are wrong.  The computations should skip NaN values rather than failing on them.  I've made the necessary one-line change on my fork of three.js and everything is working correctly.

Comment: Mugen87 is one of those who work with the core of Three.js, so he knows what he says. I prefer the common way, using valid values, rather then using NaNs of Infs, having troubles with the framework and then blaming it for bugs. An additional attribute is not such a big deal. It matters only if you try to run your app on a calculator.

Comment: NaN is a valid value according to the WebGL spec

Comment: It's okay in your specific case :) Do you seriously offer to add the checking for NaN in the core? I can't get the logics. You're telling me about kind of optimization about having less attributes and on the other hand you're saying about additional conditions in the core. So, if it's working for you, then it's okay. I can accept it )) If you don't agree about how the things work in three.js, then you can make a PR on Github.

Comment: adding a single if-statement to a function that gets called once per initialization is much better than adding 10-15% to the memory footprint of an enormous geometry object!  javascript is mostly bottlenecked by mem and gc.  I'd be happy to submit a PR

Comment: I don't know about your geometry attributes, but when it comes to points, you can simply do `curve.getPoints(...).flatMap(i => [i, i]).slice(1, -1);` to duplicate all array elements except the first and the last if you want connected `LineSegments`. Alternatively, for simple cases you can merge the geometry again into the unified one, e.g. `overallgeometry.push(singlegeometry, singlegeometry);` and it will achieve the same. I had the same problem (and annoyance) as you did, and both the above were valid solutions in my case. Maybe they will suit yours as well, to avoid potential NaN issues...